# How to show real-time suggestions (e.g. existing entries with same initial characters) while user is typing in a text field in Cocoa Touch?

Tags: cocoa-touch

I'm wondering if there is an existing class or library code in Cocoa Touch that shows the user a list of real-time suggestions while they are entering text input, with the suggestions based on similarities between what they have already entered and previous entries.

For instance, see how Safari on the iPod Touch shows realtime suggestions when you start to type in a URL, based on previously visited sites.

If there is a standard way of doing this, I'd love to know! If not, suggestions for a reasonable way to implement this -- subclass UITextField and go from there? -- would be welcome.

Comment: just to let you know that: "How to show real-time suggestions (e.g. existing entries with same initial characters) while user is typing in a text field" has a nice and sorter name: "Auto Complete" ;)

Comment: Yes, that's exactly the phrase I was looking for! I knew I was being long-winded about it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest looking at the delegate method:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
```

You'll have to roll your own auto completion view similar to what Apple uses for its suggestive auto complete feature.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check out the UITextFieldTextDidChangeNotification to see when the UITextField is changed. Look at NSNotificationCenter to see how to register an observer.